# How can I fix the Java error: myClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method?

Tags: java, swing

I'm *very* new to Java and being the GUI obsessed freak I am, got drawn to Swing. I have not much experience with Java (really basic knowledge) and I've started making a game. I want to use Swing for it and have started with some basic code for the login/register system under the guidance of a website.

However, they don't tell me how to make a button run a command, so, I scoured the internet and found ActionListener but I'm not sure how to use it. I've tried implementing it in my code but I get an error for it. I'm don't know what is wrong, I can't find anything useful on how to fix this error:

```
Apiary is not abstract and does not override abstract method
actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionListener) in
java.awt.event.ActionListener
```

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Apiary implements ActionListener {   
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Apiary");
        frame.setSize(350, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        placeComponents(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.addActionListener(placeComponents);
    }    
    private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        usernameLabel.setBounds(10,20,80,25);
        panel.add(usernameLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100,20,165,25);
        panel.add(userText);

         JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10,50,80,25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        passwordText.setBounds(100,50,165,25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(loginButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message simply means that your class does not implement all the methods in the interface. In particular `actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionListener)` is missing.

Comment: where would I put the ```actionPerformed(ActionEvent)```? Again, I'm very new so I might not know what some terms mean.

Comment: `ActionListener`s are meant to be UI callbacks, so you probably don't want your main class to be an ActionListener, but instead a separate class.

Comment: Having said that, it's very common for `ActionListener`s to be [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)... that is a class whose body exists inside the UI element's`.addActionListener` call in your code... like `loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { stuff here } })`  (except with correction line breaks and indentation)

Comment: @JaydenCollis While you removed the IDE which I agree was unnecessary, I want to point out had you use other IDE like Netbeans, there's an option to implement abstract methods when you implement an interface, no need to type them manually. Plus the built--in Swing designer is much easier to use than handwriting the layout.

Comment: @Powerlord *"it's very common for ActionListeners to be anonymous classes"* Good point. I can't recall the last time I implemented an `ActionListener` on a class (of my own writing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I fix the Java error: myClass is not abstract and does not override abstract method?

Add an `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method. Be sure to add the `@Override` notation. See other changes as noted in this working example.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Apiary implements ActionListener {   

    private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        usernameLabel.setBounds(10,20,80,25);
        panel.add(usernameLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100,20,165,25);
        panel.add(userText);

         JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10,50,80,25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
        passwordText.setBounds(100,50,165,25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(loginButton);
        Apiary apiary = new Apiary();
        loginButton.addActionListener(apiary);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("ToDo!");
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Apiary");
        frame.setSize(350, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        placeComponents(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### General tips:

1. For a log-in, I'd recommend using a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` instead of a `JFrame` to display it. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)
2. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: This fixed my code, just 1 more question what does ```@Override``` do? Is it the command for when someone clicks the button?

Comment: No. `@Override` is a notation to the compiler that this method .. overrides (or implements) a method from a class it extends or implements. If the method signature is incorrect, the compiler will issue a warning. This is more useful when overriding a method that has already been implemented in an extended classes ancestor. If it were for a method of an interface, there would *also* be a warning like you were seeing. It makes no difference to the resulting class file - by that stage, it is irrelevant.

Comment: Or to put it more simply, you put in `@Override` so that the compiler tells you when you accidentally put in the wrong method signature for something you're overriding.

Comment: Ok, I understand that @Andrew Thompson. Thanks! Although I know that this won't be the only question

Comment: *"I know that this won't be the only question"* I know you're in the right place, SO being a **Q** & A site. ;)